# Synonyms for “passing the buck”?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, synonyms

What would be a better replacement for the informal phrase “*passing the buck*” (ie. shift responsibility for something to someone else)?

I am in need of a single-word verb that captures the all-too-familiar bureaucratic practice of referring endlessly.

“*Refer to*” is too neutral of a meaning; it lacks the hypocrisy inherent in “passing the buck”.

“*Defer to*” implies a responsible act, whereby the referrer is conceding their limitations.

“*Abrogate*” is open-faced shirking of responsibility - whereas I am after the lazy bureaucratic practice of “passing the buck”.

**EXAMPLE**:

A comes to B with a problem. B is lazy and doesn’t feel like putting in the work to solve it, so they ______ to another department.

Answer (score 4):

How about **delegate**?

> to give a particular job, duty, right, etc. to someone else so that they do it for you:
>
> - *As a boss you have to delegate (responsibilities to your staff).*
> - *Authority to make financial decisions has been delegated to a special committee.*

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/delegate)]

Answer (score 3):

***shuffle** sth **off***

> **to get rid of something unwanted, usually by giving it to someone else**:

> Ex. "The local authority may then try to ***shuffle** *these responsibilities* **off*** onto another authority." [emphasis mine]

[Cambridge Online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shuffle-sth-off)

A [phrasal verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=phrasal%20verbs), and considered "*literary*"**, it fits the intended usage well.

> A comes to B with a problem. B is lazy and doesn’t feel like putting in the work to solve it, so they  *shuffled it off* (*on*)to another department.

In some circles, it has higher register than 'pass the buck", but it might also be a "cross-the-pond" thing.

Comment: **Why is this considered "literary"? My best guess? ...because it used in well-known quotes and expressions such as..."shuttle off this mortal coil", "shuffling to Babylon", or even, "shuffling off to Buffalo"...all involve movement for various reasons, often to perdition.

Answer (score 0):

> **tergiversate**: v. to evade, to equivocate using subterfuge;
> to obfuscate in a deliberate manner.

> **scrimshank**: v. (Britain, military, slang) To shirk duty.

> **bludge**: v. (Australia, New Zealand, slang) To not earn one's keep, to
> live off someone else or off welfare when one could be working.

> (Australia, New Zealand, slang) To avoid one's responsibilities; to
> leave it to others to perform duties that one is expected to perform.

> (Australia, New Zealand, slang) To do nothing, to be idle, especially
> when there is work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If A refers the problem to B, who in turn refers the problem to C, then B is **subdelegating** to C. For instance, definition 2 for "[subdelegate, v.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/192554)," Oxford English Dictionary has the following:

> 2. transitive. To delegate (authority, or an office or commission) to a subordinate person, group, or body; to delegate further.
>
> 1891   Spectator 21 Feb. 272/1   The ruler gets bored with the work, and delegates his power, which is again sub-delegated.
>
> 1918   America (N.Y.) 20 July 351/2   The active enforcement of censorship is subdelegated to the second deputy of police.
>
> 1996   Digest Environmental Law (Nexis) Sept. 11   Secretary Glickman properly delegated authority to an Assistant Secretary, who subdelegated authority to the Forest Service Chief.

This is a quirky usage. That said, so is the practice of delegating an already-delegated task *ad nauseam*. **Subdelegate** also neatly aligns with other forms of secondary assignment, like *subcontracting*, where someone contracted to do work in turn subcontracts someone else to do the work, or *subletting*, where someone who has signed a lease sublets the property to someone else for a span of time.